How to use COUNT for multiple conditions?
I have a data table city like below:



City
Population
Area




A
2500000
800


B
990000
400


C
1200000
600



I need to count the number of cities for each of below conditions:

Small: Population < 1000000 and area < 500
Medium: 1000000 < Population < 2000000 and 500 < area < 700
Big: Population > 2000000 and area > 700

The expected output:



Small
Medium
Big




1
1
1



I could only think of using CASE like this:
SELECT
    CASE WHEN population < 1000000 AND area < 500 THEN COUNT(*)
         WHEN population > 2000000 AND area > 700 THEN COUNT(*)
    ELSE COUNT(*) END AS 'big'
FROM city;

But it only returned 1 value.
Please help me to fix.
Thank you.

It's vice versa, COUNT(CASE...), not CASE...COUNT(...), search for conditional aggregation

No, it returns: "In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'fiddle.city.Population'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" (see: DBFIDDLE)

"But it only returned 1 value."  You are only selecting 1 value (CASE.... as 'big' )

In MySQL you don't even need CASE for such queries as it provides SUM(boolean expression), see https://dbfiddle.uk/NkOQg1Gt.

But counting a city with population=1000000 and area=700 as 'Medium' is not correct because of the "1000000 < Population ...  area < 700"   (see: DBFIDDLE )

You need a separate CASE statement for Small, Medium and Big

@JonasMetzler I searched conditional aggregation and tried but the results not correct. Please help check what I did wrong https://dbfiddle.uk/lJrfaS9Z

@Harper: The 0 is also counted, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/eE90wBWT   (When changing COUNT to SUM , your approach should work)

@Luuk Then change 700 to 699 if you like this more ;) I focused on explaining the syntax, not the exact values.

@Harper Just remove the ELSE 0 clauses

@Luuk Got it! I should leave out the 0 part while using COUNT. Thank you very much.

SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN population < 1000000 AND area < 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Small,
    SUM(CASE WHEN population > 1000000 AND population < 2000000 AND area > 500 AND area < 700 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Medium,
    SUM(CASE WHEN population > 2000000 AND area > 700 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Big
FROM city;


Repeating the answer from the comment, without explanation is ....(not helpful IMHO)

Using BETWEEN is far simpler because usually population is of type integer.

But care should be taken to write 500 < area < 700 as AREA BETWEEN 500 and 700. This is wrong because in this BETWEEN the values 500 and 700 are included while in the description they are not.

You'll want something like this:
SELECT
  count(IIF(population < 1000000 AND area < 500, 1, NULL)) as small,
  count(IIF((population between 1000000 AND 2000000) AND (area between 500 AND 700), 1, NULL)) as medium,
  count(IIF(population > 2000000 AND area > 700, 1, NULL)) as big
FROM cities;

You can't aggregate using the WHERE clause as each column requires a different condition. Instead you can use the fact that COUNT only includes the non-null values.
Just check for each condition using the IIF function and return 1 if true or otherwise NULL.  The count aggregate then correctly counts up only the rows that match the query.

"FUNCTION fiddle.IIF does not exist"  (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/xXZHyWcI)

@AliJ See comments below the question, it's already solved. No need to answer.

@JonasMetzler answering is useful so the question can be marked as resolved.
